# How to reduce size of an image texture

Tags: image

I currently have a texture on a pre-existing model that is 4096 x 4096 pixels.  When I export a gltf file this texture is about 28 megs.  Pretty big for what I want to do.  There's also some other ones.  I attempted to resize it by going to *Image Editor -> image -> resize*

[image]

Here I resize it to 1024 x 1024 and hit ok.
The image appears smaller on the image editor and the size says 1024 x 1024.  However when I save this or export it then it reverts back to the original image size of 4096.  Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or another step I need to reduce these images sizes?

Comment: Interesting case. The glTF exporter depends on the dirty flag to know if the image has changed. If it hasn't changed, it will use the data from the file on disk. But resizing an image does not set the dirty flag... If you "Save As" the image after resizing, it should work though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have resized your image, make sure you save the image within the Image Editor/UV Editor panel. Image > Save or Save As.